# Problems trying to watch HD videos from a mac

Tags: osx-lion, streaming, youtube, high-definition

I was wondering if anybody might be able to help with this. I am using a Mac Book Air, running MacOSX Lion and originally when I restore it to factory setting I can watch videos, say for example from youtube in FULL 1080p HD but over time when I try to view the same videos, the start to become glitchy and jumpy to the point where I just can't watch them.

It there any way to fix this without having to do another full system restore?

Thanks

Comment: How old is the macbook air? Specs on it? What other software or processes are you installing or running on it as time goes on? I'm wondering if its just a system resources thing. Airs arent the beefiest of machines, especially the ones from a year or two ago anyway. With enough stuff running, I could see one having a stutter when playing really hi res video if there is really almost anything else running.

Comment: Does it happen when you shut down all other applications?

Comment: Well, in addition to what @Paperlantern said, it's just Flash and OS X. They don't really love each other. Have you upgraded to the latest version?

Comment: hey thanks for the responses.

It has a 128gb SSD and 4gb of RAM....Even if I shut every application I have down bar the browser, it still happens

Comment: Does it depend on the browser? Did you try and update Flash? (Please ping me with `@slhck` if you post a reply)

Comment: hey @slhck ..... no i tried it in firefox opera and safari and it's still the same, I also have the latest version of flash.

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] the question and post a screenshot of `Activity Monitor` when you experience this problem. So you say this hasn't been an issue when you first got the Mac?

Comment: @slhck no it was fine and when I restore it, it does be find again. It seems to be ok when I watch it on normal size screen but when I put it to full screen, thats when I get mainly get the problem

Answer (score 0):

might take it to an apple store - there have been problems with lion and display hardware. My MacBook Pro was out of warranty, yet apple replaced the mainboard, at no charge, when I told them about the video problems I was having.  Voila - fixed.  I never received any kind of recall notice about it.